# shell_exec command js-beautify not run working

Tags: php, laravel, js-beautify

I'm trying to run this code in the controller

```
echo shell_exec(' echo 3');
echo shell_exec('cat m.html | js-beautify  --type html -o m.html ; echo 43');
echo shell_exec(' echo 53');
```

I got as an output

> 3
>   53

and  m.html is not beautified also when I run the same command through command line the file is beautified.

Comment: You should try using the full path to js-beautify

Comment: It did n't work also

Comment: well, you should try capturing the error message and exit code.  Unix and linux commands have exit codes and stderr streams for a reason.   My guess is that your current directory doesn't have the m.html file.

Comment: I didn't get any thing as output that's why I echo value after the command.

Comment: You should do some more research on what I wrote above. You should try to understand the difference between stdout and stderr streams and the exit code. Because the output (stdout) is just one stream that doesn't contain error data.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely this is to do with paths. You will need to provide the full paths for both `m.html` and `js-beautify` executable. Also make sure the relevant execute permissions are set for the web server user.

```
// get the location of m.html if it's in the same folder as your PHP file
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/m/html';
echo shell_exec("/path/to/js-beautify --type html -o $path -f $path');
```

It might be worth removing the `-o` file and letting output go to standard output, i.e. passed back to your web page, so that you can see if it's writing to the same file. Maybe check timestamps too?

Also I believe you can directly pass the file to js-beautify (or with the -f flag), meaning if there were errors reading your file you would see js-beautify's errors instead of nothing.